Implement interface with an auto-property in TypeScript
I have a react-component that acts as a container for multiple text-fields.  Initially there's just a single textbox, however the user can dynamically add more.
So I have a model for every textfield:
interface TextFieldProps
{
    value: string,
    setValue: (newValue: string) => void
}

which is used in my MyTextField-component:
function MyTextField(props: TextFieldProps) => {
    return (<TextField value={props.value} onChange={props.setValue} />)
}

As you can see MyTextField is just a wrapper around a MUI-textbox. When the onChange-event on that textbox is triggered, the setValue-function passed to my wrapper is executed. This way I can grab the textbox's values inside my cntainer and also call some code whenever one of the textboxes changes.
So finally here's the Container-component
function Container() => {
    const[textFields, setTextFields] = useState<TextFieldProps>[]();

    return(
        <>
            { 
                textFields.map(t => <MyTextField value={ t.value } setValue={ t.setValue } />
            }
        </>
    )
}

However I have no idea how to create an instance of the TextFieldProps in order to build new wrapper-components from them.
What I want to achieve is have my container access to the containing textbox-values and their setter-functions.

Do you mean something like interfaces MyTextFieldProps extends TextFieldProps {...}? Or what do you mean by "have my container access to the containing textbox-values and their setter-functions"?

@Anton I want my container to keep track of the textbox' values. So it should be able to get and assign the textbox's current value somehow.

In order to control multiple textboxes at a time, one way to do it is to have a useState in which you have a map where key is a unique key of a text field and value is the value of the input.
Then, you can use your array of textboxes (eg. ['firstName', 'lastName', 'address1', 'address2']) and map the MyTextField retrieving text field value by its key and setter function by the makeHandleChange factory.
This way, you can easily access textboxes' values and adjust the factory function to your business logic.


type Values = Record<string, string>;

function Container() => {
  const [textFields, setTextFields] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [values, setValues] = useState<Values>({});

  const makeHandleChange = (key: string) => (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setValues(prevValues => ({ ...prevValues, [key]: e.target.value }))
  }

  return (<>
    {
      textFields.map(textFieldKey => <MyTextField key={textFieldKey} value={values[textFieldKey} setValue={makeHandleChange(textFieldKey)} />
     } </>
    )
  }



Without makeHandleChange factory:


type Values = Record<string, string>;

function Container() => {
  const [textFields, setTextFields] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [values, setValues] = useState<Values>({});

  const handleChange = (key: string, e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setValues(prevValues => ({ ...prevValues, [key]: e.target.value }))
  }

  return (<>
    {
      textFields.map(textFieldKey => <MyTextField key={textFieldKey} value={values[textFieldKey} setValue={(e) => handleChange(textFieldKey, e)} />
     } </>
    )
  }




that makeHandleChange makes me headaches because of the three arrow-functions. Can you break this down a bit further?

@MakePeaceGreatAgain updated the answer. The idea of makeHandleChange is to avoid arrow functions in JSX since on each render of MyTextField we gonna create a new arrow function every time. The makeHandleChange might save some memory since we will reuse the same function on each render of the MyTextField.

To achieve this, you can manage the state of text fields as an array of objects in your Container component. Each object will have a value and an id to uniquely identify each text field (for example, the date created, or the index, or the guuid, whatever), ensuring the state updates independently. Please take a look at sandbox here
Define the Text Field Component
Create a wrapper around the MUI TextField that takes value and setValue as props.
// MyTextField.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { TextField } from '@mui/material';

interface TextFieldProps {
    value: string;
    setValue: (newValue: string) => void;
}

function MyTextField({ value, setValue }: TextFieldProps) {
    return (
        <TextField
            value={value}
            onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth
            margin="normal"
        />
    );
}

export default MyTextField;

Define the Container Component
In the Container component, manage the state as an array of objects. Each object will hold a value and an id.
// Container.tsx
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import MyTextField from './MyTextField';

interface TextFieldData {
    value: string;
    id: number;
}

function Container() {
    // State to hold the array of text field data
    const [textFields, setTextFields] = useState<TextFieldData[]>([
        { value: '', id: Date.now() }, // Initial text field
    ]);

    // Function to add a new text field
    const addTextField = () => {
        setTextFields((prevFields) => {
            const updatedFields = [
                ...prevFields,
                { value: '', id: Date.now() }, // Add a new text field with a unique ID
            ];
            console.log('After adding new field:', updatedFields); // Log the state after adding a field
            return updatedFields;
        });
    };

    // Function to update a specific text field's value
    const updateTextField = (id: number, newValue: string) => {
        setTextFields((prevFields) => {
            const updatedFields = prevFields.map((field) =>
                field.id === id ? { ...field, value: newValue } : field
            );
            console.log('After updating field:', updatedFields); // Log the state after updating a field
            return updatedFields;
        });
    };

    return (
        <div style={{ padding: '20px', maxWidth: '600px', margin: '0 auto' }}>
            {textFields.map((field) => (
                <MyTextField
                    key={field.id}
                    value={field.value}
                    setValue={(newValue) => updateTextField(field.id, newValue)}
                />
            ))}
            <button onClick={addTextField} style={{ marginTop: '10px' }}>
                Add Text Field
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Container;

Explanation

The state (textFields) is an array of objects where each object has
a value and a unique id. The id ensures each text field is
independently managed.
The addTextField function adds a new object to the state array.
The updateTextField function updates a specific text field’s value
using its id.

